# Create CommandBarButton and fire Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I try to fire a sub on a comandbar button. I have the following code but it always gives me the error: "The Macro 'xxx.xlsm!Cbm_Active_Value' can not be executed. Either it is not available in the workbook or macros are not activated" (I translated the error message, so this is not the original).

```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Dim objPopUp As CommandBarPopup
   Dim objBtn As CommandBarButton
   With Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
      On Error Resume Next
      .Controls("MyFunction").Delete
      On Error GoTo 0
      Set objPopUp = .Controls.Add( _
         Type:=msoControlPopup, _
         before:=.Controls.Count, _
         temporary:=True)
   End With
   objPopUp.Caption = "&Actionen"
   Set objBtn = objPopUp.Controls.Add
   With objBtn
      .Caption = "Do Action"
      .OnAction = "Cbm_Active_Value"
      .Style = msoButtonCaption
   End With

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   With Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
      On Error Resume Next
      .Controls("&MyFunction").Delete
      On Error GoTo 0
   End With
End Sub

Sub Cbm_Active_Value()
MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub
```

Comment: So... did you enable macros?

Comment: where do you pleaced your `Cbm_Active_Value` macro? It should be in _standart_ module rather than in workbook or worksheet module

Comment: ah. that was the mistake. thank you simoco!